# Fitting a curve to my data

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, data-analysis

I got some data of the I-V characteristics of a solar cell (diode) in the dark and I have been trying to fit the data with the standard equation:

$$ I = I_0(e^{qv/nkT} - 1) $$

The below table is my data :
[image: Data]

I tried to use desmos graphing calculator for fitting the curve(I am trying to find $I_0$ and n and all other values are known), but even using reasonable bounds as shown in the below figure :
[image: Graph]
The fit is very poor. It gives values of $I_0$ as $10^-9$ and n as 1.967. I realize my data maybe wrong, but is there any way to make this work?

Comment: In the last box on the left hand side, you have $10^{-9}<a<5\cdot 10^{-8}$. Then the best fit parameters seem to include $a=1\times 10^{-9}$. That makes it look like your fit is running into some predefined boundary you set, and you need to allow $a$ to go to lower values. There may be other issues, but that jumps out at me.

Comment: Relatedly, $b$ is very close to your upper bound of $2$. I bet you need to let $b$ go to larger values. Your data is quite linear; $e^{x/b}-1$ will be approximately linear when $b$ is large.

Comment: Are you sure that the equation that you are trying to use is applicable to solar cells in the dark?  Your data look quite linear, implying that the answer is "no".

Comment: @Andrew but b is the ideality factor of a diode, so it must be between 1 and 2.

Comment: @DavidWhite Well that's what my lab manual and wikipedia tells me, and I think my data must be wrong somehow since other people who did the experiment got an exponential kind of graph.

Comment: @Andrew If I put no bounds on a, I get values a in order of 10^-17 and b = 2 and it's still not a good fit.

Comment: @NeeladriReddy If your question is about fitting your data, then I'm just telling you that $b=2$ is not a large enough value of $b$ to fit your data. If your question is why your data is not well fit by some parameter values you expect, you may want to change the focus of your question to give more details on the experimental procedure and ask why you are not measuring the behavior you expect. One thing I'd double check is that all the units are correct.

Comment: Your data looks suspect to me. The graph of V:I is approximately linear and while I would expect this to be the case for V < 0.6V it seems unlikely the graph would remain linear up to nearly 1.5V.

Comment: If you're confident the data is correct use the approximation $e^{qv/nkT} \approx 1 + \frac{qv}{nkT}$ as this is valid in the linear region. Then your equation becomes $I = I_0 \frac{qv}{nkT}$ and you can fit this using linear regression.

Comment: @John Rennie Wierdly enough that linear approximation fits reasonably, I tried the linear thing but forgot the 1 due to my sleep addled state. I am sure the data recorded is wrong, but right now I just care about fitting the curve. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew I am sure my data is wrong, but I think as you said a linear regression give a good fit.

Comment: @NeeladriReddy, get a look at other people's data, ask them how they collected that data, tell them how you collected your data, and look for differences in experimental technique and differences in measurement devices.

Comment: @David White I would do that except that the laboratory period is over, and no one tells me anything.

Comment: @NeeladriReddy, after the assignment is turned in, you may still want to ask your peers what they did.  That information will tend to improve your lab technique and future lab grades.  If your peers are still "tight lipped", you should ask your instructor for a critique after the lab is graded.

Comment: @DavidWhite I will do that, but for right now what should I do? The data is unusable, should I just write in my report that the data is unusable and I tried my best and turn it in?

Comment: @NeeladriReddy, you need to talk to your instructor ASAP, and get his feedback.

Comment: @DavidWhite I will do that, though I am afraid. Just grit my teeth and do it I guess.